# How to recognize moving an image from inserting a new one in the froala editor?

Tags: javascript, froala

I am using Froala WYSIWYG editor with draggable plugin and `imageMove: true` option, so I can move already inserted images in the editor. I am using also [drop event](https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/examples/drop-content) and I would like to distinguish between moving an existing image and inserting a new one into the editor.

```js
froala.events.on('drop', event => {
    const files = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files
    const isImageMove = ??? // This should recognize if image was already inserted in the editor and now it was just moved.
    console.log(isImageMove ? 'Image was moved' : 'Image was inserted')
})
```

Is there any way how to achieve this?